# What is the black piece above the bottom bracket on this bike?

Tags: road-bike, parts

I came across the 2018 Specialized Diverge road bike. What is the little black piece attached to the downtube and seat tubes?

[image]

Comment: and I bet it costs a lot!   I have my tools in a small triangle frame bag that hangs inside the main triangle straight behind the headset.  Can even be accessed while riding.  For me, weight-forward was more use than weight low.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a SWAT box (tube, co2, levers and multitool) see https://www.cyclingabout.com/2018-specialized-diverge-light-touring-bikes [image: https://www.topvelo.fr/documents/Image/specialized-diverge-2018-12.jpg] from https://www.topvelo.fr/actualite-materiel-velo-nouveau-specialized-diverge-serieusement-rapide-serieusement-fun-3-993.html

Comment: Spot on. Specialized make them for a few of their  road bikes